# Unable to use asm functions in lambda?

Tags: c++, avr-gcc

The following snippet [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/vUXLaj) in Godbolt compiler:

```
#define cli()  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cli" ::: "memory")

void (*q)() = [](){ cli(); };
```

The error is `error: expected ')' before '::'` at line 1.

But if I wrap the assembly function in a regular C function, it [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/RU-hQE):

```
#define cli()  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cli" ::: "memory")

void foo() { cli(); }

void (*q)() = [](){ foo(); };
```

How so?

This is a minimal example using the Arduino framework code, and the `cli()` definition comes from the framework itself. So I cannot change it.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you add white-space(s) between the `:`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler bug. Compilers based on gcc 7 or earlier has this bug. It is fixed in gcc 8.

(If you remove the `::: "memory"` part, compilation succeeds with gcc 7. But the generated assembly is wrong, `cli` is put outside the lambda, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6xtXXC))